# How to use Python launcher "py"?

Tags: python, anaconda, launcher

I installed Python 3.6 from Anaconda.

I want to run Python script using "Python launcher" so that I can use shebang line to specify the Python environment for each individual script.

However, when I type "py" in conda prompt or windows CMD, it says 'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

What should I do in order to use "py" command to launch Python script?

Thanks!

Comment: `py` is not installed with Anaconda, as far as I know. You should use Conda environments

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please let me know what does "use Conda environments" mean?

Comment: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html